# BigBen wireless gamepad does not connect

Tags: 10.04, gamepad

The gamepad is more or less a clone of a xbox controller (IIRC it is even from the same manufacturer), labeled PCPADRFLX. `lsusb` lists the receiver as `ID 1a34:0801`.

`dmesg | grep input` reads

> [6880.468415] input: ACRUX RF USB GAMEPAD 8206 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:10.1/usb2/2-2/2-2.3/2-2.3:1.0/input/input17

Unfortunately, while the receiver is recognized, the gamepad itself does not connect. Usually after pressing a button on it the LED would light up once to indicate it has connected, however it just blinks as it does when no receiver is connected at all.

So, how can I make the gamepad work?

Comment: I [read](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=959127) that it works under gentoo, so maybe someone who knows that better than me can figure out the difference

Answer (score 2):

**tips** is a good treat to search google with the id of lsusb with this type of problem exam... 1a34:0801

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=825464

Comment: I *did* google that id, but even searching on ubuntuforums I did not find this specific thread - which looks helpful indeed, I never found instructions how to actually make the driver sync, so thank you already. Since I can't check these instructions at home before the bounty expires, I'll award it on good faith and accept later if it works.

Answer (score 0):

Have you seen this page?

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Xbox360Controller

They talk about drivers which may help you.

**EDIT**: There is also a userspace driver: http://pingus.seul.org/~grumbel/xboxdrv/ if you don't want to use the kernel module for some reason.

Comment: I tried that (see [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?s=20cea418ad19aedccb14b37783e0336f&p=6035529&postcount=1)), but seems different enough from a real xBox controller to not work :( I modified grumbels driver to recognize it, but still there was no way of connecting. The win driver seems to cause a permanent sync-fire by software, which the xbox driver apparently doesn't

Answer (score 0):

I once got the black BigBen Wireless gamepad working, but I forgot how to. I remember that I installed a lot of stuff (also the x360 driver for Linux) and suddenly it worked. I can't remember which version of ubuntu it was. It must have been 9.04 or 9.10.

I remember I played Super Mayo Chronicles with it and it worked fine. So there is a way. If someone finds out how, a documentation would be great. Next time I try I will write down every single step I make.